# Downloading files from Blob in php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently working on a site which is intended to let multiple users upload/download files from a DB. The uploading and storing files within Blobs seems to work. However when downloading/opening these files, I've encountered some problems.

While .pdf-files and .txt-files can be downloaded and opened without any issues, other formats such as Word-documents (can however be restored upon opening) or .jpeg-images (can't be opened at all) can't be opened properly (the file-sizes and extensions are correct however).

My download script looks looks as such (bear in mind that MySql statements/returned rows are handled in other classes):

```
<?php

require_once("the classes I need to reach");

$dl = $_GET['dl'];

$FileClass = new file_class();

$FileClass->search(" WHERE file_id = '".$dl."'");

header("Content-Length: " . $FileClass->getSize());
header("Content-Type: " . $FileClass->getType());
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $FileClass->getName() . "\r\n\r\n");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Pragma: public");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");

$tbd = $FileClass->getContent();

echo $tbd;

exit;
?>
```

In before rants about not using DB's for direct filestorage: it's required for my assignment, nothing I can do about it. Thus, am I missing something here?

Comment: How could we tell if you missed sg, if the most important bits of the code are hidden in `file_class()` class?

Comment: I suggest you look for other output from your script. Maybe there is some output which scrambles your file output. Also I suggest you look for control characters and remove those via `trim()`.